# My first time with IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a home network and am playing around with IIS. I have developed an ASP.NET application using visual studio 2010 and want to deploy it to my windows 2008 R2 web server. However I have never used IIS before and have no clue what I'm doing. Anyone got any good URLs? All I want to do is publish my web app to the web server and run it. Should be simple, right? I don't have a domain, just a WORKGROUP.

Thanks,
Mark.

**EDIT**

I tried to Publish the Web Site within Visual Studio and I got this in the output:

```
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\test\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Pre-compiling Web Site

Building directory '/test/App_Code/'.
Building directory '/test/controls/'.
Building directory '/test/'.
Pre-compilation Complete
------ Publish started: Project: C:\...\test\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to site http://magnesium:888...
Error: The operation could not be completed 
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas? Magnesium is the name of the web server. If I browse to the website from my workstation I get:

```
Server Error
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

**EDIT 2**

If I browse to the site on the web server, I get this output:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. Detailed Error Information
Module DirectoryListingModule 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x00000000 
Requested URL http://localhost:888/ 
Physical Path D:\sites\test 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous
```

**EDIT 3**

I've now successfully transferred the application to the web server by mapping a drive and simply publishing to the mapped drive. When I browse to it on the server I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list Detailed Error Information
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated 
Error Code 0x8007000d 
Requested URL http://magnesium:888/default.aspx 
Physical Path D:\sites\test\default.aspx 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous
```

Any ideas - wow this seems hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for VS2005, but the processes is similar: [Deploying ASP.NET Web Application](http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/deploy-asp.net.aspx)

**Edit:**
If you browse to the site from the computer (magnesium) it'll give you a much more detailed error. Otherwise you'll have to dig through the IIS logs to figure out exactly what's going on. Could be as simple as IUSR_Magnesium doesn't have read access to the folder.

**Edit 2:**
That error indicates you have no default document for the directory (ie index.asp, or default.asp; whatever it is configured to be). If your app does not implement default document functionality, it's not working.

(I have to admit you're approaching the limit of my knowledge in ASP.NET apps; but if you can't get it working, the experts over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) would know more).

Comment: Hi Chris, I added Edit 2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See edit number 2

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it. First issue was permissions on the web server. I granted rights to write to the web server, mapped a drive and was able to publish fine. The error "HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error" was fixed using the procedure on this [page](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7). Thanks Chris for your help - it's all up and running sweet now.